# Redirect link opens app and app store sequentially

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, redirect, app-store

I've run into a problem where a client's website opens the app but then immediately opens the app store and pops a message saying "This app is currently not available in your country or region".

If I type the url that the app is expecting into Safari then it opens the app, and does what's expected of it. This makes me think that there's something wrong with the website that is opening the app.

I have a suspicion that there's something wrong or missing on the website but I don't know what.

A while ago the Firebase cocoapods were updated and the website would no longer trigger the correct AppDelegate methods to handle deep linking. However I found that I just needed to add an entry to the info.plist and it resolved it. So I'm not sure if there's more that I need to do because of the Firebase update.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is for coding specific issues and most questions need to include the code you're asking about. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Include the code and troubleshooting in the question and we'll take a look!